# iTextSharp with multiple signatures and file attachments

Tags: c#, pdf, certificate, itext

I have what I think is an unusual problem for witch I can’t find a solution.
I’m using iTextSharp to sign PDF documents with multiple digital certificates. So far so good. Everything works fine.
Now my client wants to be able to attach a text message to the signature every time someone signs a file.
I thought about using the location or reason fields to add the text but these fields aren’t big enough.
Is there a way to attach files to PDF documents without invalidating previous signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding file attachments to a PDF file will (according to Adobe Acrobat/Reader) break existing signatures because adding attachments is not an allowed action for any type of signature.

You can use form fields, though, if the signatures you use allow form fill-ins. If you can go that way, have a look at [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures), a White Paper by Bruno Lowagie (iText Software), especially at section 2.5 "Signatures in PDF and workflow".

While the code samples are written in Java, the author is confident that the Java examples are also easy to understand for C# developers who are using iTextSharp instead of iText.

The C#-ified samples can be checked out from [the iTextSharp SVN repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/502/tree/tutorial/signatures/).

Comment: Thank you very much. After reading the PDF you linked I finality found a solution. Form fields are the key.